# Regex match only if word count between 1-50

Tags: python, regex

So I have this code:

```
(r'\[quote\](.+?)\[/quote\]')
```

What I want to do is to change the regex so it only matches if the text within [quote] [/quote] is between 1-50 words.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Edit: Removed confusing html code in the regex example. I am *NOT* trying to match HTML.

Comment: Before you go on with your code, please take a look at the most upvoted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags.

Comment: I don't parse html with regex, I parse bbcode.

Comment: Good to know that bbcode is regular.

Comment: What would you do if there are more than 50 'words', leave them alone?

Comment: What I really want is another regex for quotes more than 50 words.

Comment: Then, `1-50 < n < 51 - infinity` roughly equals `r'(?s)\[quote\]((?:(?!\[/quote\]).)+)\[/quote\]'`

Comment: Almost works but not if the quote have a newline inside.

Comment: @Spindel - Really? `(?s)` Dot-All. I asume you didn't try to test it..

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is, depending on how you define a "word."

I would do so separately from regex, but if you want to use regex, you could probably do:

```
r"\[quote\](.+?\s){1,49}[/quote\]"
```

That will match between 2 and 50 words (since it demands a trailing `\s`, it can't match ONE)

Crud, that also won't match the LAST word, so let's do this instead:

```
r"\[quote\](.+?(?:\s.+?){1,49})\[/quote\]"
```

Comment: +1. And good point talking about the definition of a word. E.g. how many words does "匈牙利共和国中国古称马扎儿" have?

Comment: That's a good question. Maybe counting characters is a better way to go? And if so, could you update your answer with example of character count instead of word count?

Comment: `(.+?\s){1,49}` Even though lazy quantifier, this will match 5000 + 49 whitespace to get at the `[/quote]` if it has to.

Comment: @sln I think you're mistaken. I don't have any quantifier after the `\s`, and my `{m,n}` is after the capture group. It must in fact be between 1 and 49 instances of `SOMETHING` followed by whitespace.

Comment: Btw, performance wise, could it be faster to count characters instead of words?

Comment: @adsmith - No, not mistaken. The dot `.` matches whitespace. If you have a string like this `[quote] < 40 million whitespace's > [/quote]` your regex will match it.

Comment: @adsmith - You could however exclude whitespace in leiu of the dot. `\[quote\](\S+(?:\s\S+){1,49})\[/quote\]"` , but you have to work out edge conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a definite misuse of regexes for a lot of reasons, not the least of which is the problem matching [X]HTML as @Hyperboreus noted, but if you really insist you could do something along the lines of `([a-zA-Z0-9]\s){1}{49}`.

For the record, I don't recommend this.

Comment: Maybe I should have removed the <blockquote> part because it is what I am replacing the BBcode with, not part of the match itself.